# Converting string into time and date

Tags: php

I'm parsing data from an API. I m getting start time (`634942260000000000`) and end time (`634942332000000000`). Can you guide me how can I decode the this string to get the formated time/date?

Comment: What have you tried? What format is the time in when you receive it from the API?

Comment: We don't know what format this is, so we can't really give advice on how to decode it

Comment: I m getting data from this txt file.http://122.155.1.10/program-info/pginfo-20130119.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They look like server ticks to me.

```
$seconds = $ticks / 1000000;
$date = date("d-m-Y", $seconds);
```

Comment: Hahahah I thought I was looking at the C# tag.

Comment: @Zarathos I tried but it returns 1969-12-31. it must be current date

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php does what you need, pass the format you would like as the first parameter and your time in milliseconds as the second.